# convert IList object to List

Tags: c#, list, asp.net-web-api, swagger, application-xml

```
    [System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
    [System.Web.Http.Route("acDetails")]
    [ResponseType(typeof(List<AutoCompleteCombine>))]
    public IHttpActionResult acDetails(string Text)
    {
                    var db = new ModelName();
                    var DetailsList = (IList)null;
                    try
                    {
                        var DetailsIListXX = (from a in db.Tablename
                                          where a.ColumnName.StartsWith(Text)
                                          select a.ColumnName).Distinct().ToList();
                        DetailsList = DetailsIListXX.Select(x => new { ColumnNameChange= x }).ToArray();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {

                    }
                    return Ok(DetailsList);
     }

//properties
    public class AutoCompleteCombine
    {
        public string ColumnNameChange { get; set; }

    }
```

Above code works for 'application/json' and 'text/json' response types and gets error for application/xml and text/xml responses in swagger.

Exception Message:The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/xml; charset=utf-8'

converting the response To List with AutoCompleteCombine class properties would fix the error i think.

Any suggestions to convert ilist to List in this object type case

Thanks

Comment: Does the response give a 200 OK?  If you are getting 200 than the data in response is not xml or there is a header that you have to remove.  Xml should start with <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> .  If you are not getting 200 OK than something is wrong with the request.  Post the error.

Comment: 200 ok for application/json and text/json response types....and error for application/xml and text/xml responses....and the Exception Message for XML response types: The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/xml; charset=utf-8'-@jdweng

Comment: Ignore the Xml error until you get a valid 200 OK in the response.  First we have to understand why the XML request is failing.  Do you have an examples of a working XML Request?  What error are you getting instead of the 200 OK.  Is it 500 or something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing with this line:

```cs
DetailsList = DetailsIListXX.Select(x => new { ColumnNameChange= x }).ToArray()
```

is creating `Array` of anonymous types (see `new { ColumnNameChange...}`), but instead you need to return `List<AutoCompleteCombine>`:

```cs
DetailsIListXX.Select(x => new AutoCompleteCombine { ColumnNameChange = x }).ToList();
```